# In pandas python, how do I get rid of the extra column header with index numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run a transpose on sample data, I get an extra column header with numbers
[image]

How do I get rid of it?
Sample data that I keep trying to add a table but will only let me copy as an image
[image]

Code that doesn't work

```
AIR_LINES_TRANSPOSE = AIR_LINES.transpose()
AIR_LINES_TRANSPOSE.drop_index(Inplace = True, Drop = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use df.rename to rename the column headers then drop the duplicate header row. This is an example with a sample set:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({0:['A',14,15,16,15,15,18,19,10,11], 1:['B',13,17,19,14,16,14,13,14,16]})
df=df.rename(columns={0:"A", 1:"B"})
df=df.iloc[1:,:]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AIR_LINES_TRANSPOSE = AIR_LINES.T  # transpose
AIR_LINES_TRANSPOSE = AIR_LINES_TRANSPOSE.droplevel(0, axis=1)  # drop first column level
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and got this error: ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.